# How to detect failure and reset/restart webassembly Module?

Tags: javascript, c++, webassembly

I am trying to get some C++ functions to run on the browser using WebSssembly. I am following this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/emscripting-a-c-library). I would like to know:

1. How to detect (at JS side) an 'uncaught exception' coming from C++ code?
2. How to reset/restart WebAssembly Module generated by `emcc` in a way that avoids memory leaks?

Adding exception catching functionality (`DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0`) seems to increase the file size too much.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

The sample C++ code is as follows:

```
// C++ source code (fib.cc)

#include <stdexcept>
#include <emscripten.h>

extern "C" {

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
int fib(int n) {
  if (n > 12) {
    throw std::out_of_range("input out of range");
  }
  int i, t, a = 0, b = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    t = a + b;
    a = b;
    b = t;
  }
  return b;
}

// >>
// other functions with allocations/deallocations

} // end of extern C
```

It is built with the command:

```
emcc -O3 -s WASM=1 -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='["cwrap"]' fib.cc
```

It is tested with a webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>WASM Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="a.out.js"></script>
<script>
"use strict";

Module.onRuntimeInitialized = _ => {
  const fib = Module.cwrap('fib', 'number', ['number']);
  console.log(fib(10));
  console.log(fib(14)); // causes exception
};

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

> How to detect (at JS side) an 'uncaught exception' coming from C++ code?

You have to catch the exceptions using `try-catch` blocks ([tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp)).

Example:

```
try {
    console.log( fib(14) );
}
catch ( e ) {
    console.error( e );
}
```

But, as of now, it is propagated as a pointer so you will see some number in the console:

```
5249672
```

If you want to get a proper error message in JS then you have to write a [binding](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html#embind) in your C++ code:

```
#include <emscripten/bind.h>

std::string getExceptionMessage(int eptr)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<std::exception*>(eptr)->what();
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(getExceptionMessageBinding)
{
    emscripten::function("getExceptionMessage", &getExceptionMessage);
};
```

This would be exposed in the JS code through the `Module` object. You can use it in JS code like this:

```
try {
    console.log( fib(14) );
}
catch ( e ) {
    console.error( Module.getExceptionMessage(e) );
}
```

Output (exception is thrown):

```
input out of range
```

Here's the GitHub [issue](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/6330) where this has been discussed and [suggested](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/6330#issuecomment-568239092).

I've compiled this code with exceptions enabled with C++11 and [bindings](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/bind.h.html#_CPPv419EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS4name) like this:

```
~/emsdk/upstream/emscripten$ ./em++ -std=c++11 -Os -fexceptions --bind 
                             -s WASM=1
                             -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='["cwrap"]'
                             -s DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0
                             fib.cc
```

Here's another similar GitHub [issue](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/pull/7405) discussing another approach to this.

---

> Adding exception catching functionality (`DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0`) seems to increase the file size too much.

If your concern is the increased size of the output files, you can disable exception handling altogether and resort to error checking with invalid values or error codes returning by the function(s) e.g. -1 if the input is invalid.

However, here's an observation:

The file sizes of the previous build were:

```
110K - a.out.js
187K - a.out.wasm
```

The exception handling and RTTI for bindings were part of this.

I stripped the code and used inline JS using [EM_ASM](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/emscripten.h.html#c.EM_ASM) to throw a JS Error in the following code snippet:

```
#include <emscripten.h>

extern "C" {

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
int fib(int n) {
    if (n > 12) {
        EM_ASM(
            throw Error("out_of_range");    // JS error with EM_ASM
        );
    }

    int a {0}, b {1};
    for ( int i {0}; i < n; ++i ) {
        const auto t = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = t;
    }
    return b;
}

}
```

Compiled with exceptions disabled:

```
$ ./em++ -std=c++11 -Os
  -fno-exceptions 
  -s WASM=1
  -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='["cwrap"]'
  fib1.cc
```

Here's the HTML file (`fib1.html`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>WASM Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="a.out.js"></script>
<script>
"use strict";

Module.onRuntimeInitialized = _ => {
    const fib = Module.cwrap('fib', 'number', ['number']);

    try {
        console.log(fib(10));
        console.log(fib(14));
    }
    catch ( e ) {
        console.error(e);
     }
};

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Console Output (exception caught):

```
89
fib1.html:21 Error: out_of_range
    at Array.ASM_CONSTS (a.out.js:1)
    at _emscripten_asm_const_i (a.out.js:1)
    at wasm-function[1]:0x6b
    at Module._fib (a.out.js:1)
    at Object.Module.onRuntimeInitialized (fib1.html:18)
    at doRun (a.out.js:1)
    at run (a.out.js:1)
    at runCaller (a.out.js:1)
    at removeRunDependency (a.out.js:1)
    at receiveInstance (a.out.js:1)
```

And, the file sizes were:

```
15K - a.out.js
246 - a.out.wasm (bytes)
```

Throwing a JS Error still works with exceptions disabled and the generated file sizes are far less. You might want to explore this more. Maybe, create some classes inherited from Error with extended functionality. However, the exceptions that are thrown from the standard APIs such as [`std::vector::at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) won't work and cause termination. So, you need to be considerate about those while disabling exceptions.

---

> How to reset/restart WebAssembly Module generated by `emcc` in a way that avoids memory leaks?

As of now, there is no such API to reset/restart a module. The module itself is automatically garbage collected when it is no longer referenced. You don't have to care about the memory leak in this case. The JS runtime is responsible for this.

But, the C++ object created by the JS code should be destroyed using [`Module.destroy`](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/module.html#Module.destroy) if it is managing resources (memory, file handles, etc.). The Garbage Collector (GC) won't call the destructor when it collects the object which would result in a memory/resource leak. Calling `Module.destory` will invoke the destructor and there won't be any memory leaks. Right now, your question doesn't have such an object. So, be mindful when you do and call `Module.destory` when required.

As for the allocations/deallocations in your C++ code, you *yourself* are responsible for the deallocation of the resources that you allocate. Here are a few points that might help you in this regard:

- Avoid [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).
- Follow the [rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) religiously.
- Use [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii)-based C++ standard library facilities for automatic memory management such as [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) / [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) along with [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) / [`std::make_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared).
- Look for STL containers such as [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), etc. for storing and managing collections rather than resorting to writing your own. The standard stuff is well-tested hence fewer worries about bugs.
- Always refer to the documentation of the APIs that you plan to use. Verify if an API allocates resources that you might have to deallocate a certain way after use.

---

Here's a thread on loading a WASM module: [Loading WebAssembly modules efficiently](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/04/loading-wasm)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. However, my aim is to make the module failure resistant. I am only doing the porting part and I cannot assume that the module(s) wont fail. Failure is inevitable (I am using multiple libraries, written by multiple people). And when it happens, I want to reload the module (so that I can guarantee that the outputs are not corrupted). I was looking for an answer that would help me to reinitialize the 'Module' somehow. Seems like that is not possible. Anyway, have your +100.

Comment: You're welcome! Right. So, there is more to this. :) Right now, the question is more focused around error-handling and avoiding memory leaks (i.e. avoid leaks and no need to restart). But, your actual requirement is focused on porting involving multiple libraries. Can you make another post focused on these things? Post its link here, I'll try to look into that. You must add your whole scenario of porting like how many libraries roughly, how the error-handling is approached (error codes, exceptions, etc.), and examples on this _so that I can guarantee that the outputs are not corrupted_.

Comment: @AxeonThra: An idea that you can explore is a _sentinel module_ (kind of wrapper) that handles the errors internally and reinitiates/reinitializes the required values - one that goes of scope last.